# I want to create admin grid using ui component . if you have any article or blog then please share

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

**Issue:**

I am trying to create admin grid in Magento 2 but I stuck. If you have created admin grid using UI Component Then Please Share With me.

**Thank you**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below blog helps you to create admin grid.

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2016/04/10/magento2-grid-ui-component/

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to first read of actual works of Magento2 UI component.

(1)`https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-create-a-grid-using-ui-component/`

(2) There is a one link about Magento2 UI component you can download from here.
`http://uk.magetitans.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Mage-Titans-Maria-Kerns.pdf`