# Adminside Menu which display a table details

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, uicomponent

I'm trying to create a menu in admin side which show a table. now i'm done with adding new menu and which has two sublevel. i need to display third level having a table **app/code/Dyode/Pricebeat/view/adminhtml/layout/dyode_pricebeat_form_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="styles"/>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="menu">
        <action method="setActive">
            <argument name="itemId" xsi:type="string">Dyode_Pricebeat::forms</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="page.title">
        <action method="setTitleClass">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">complex</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <uiComponent name="dyode_pricebeat_form_listing"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Dyode/Pricebeat/view/adminhtml/layout/dyode_pricebeat_form_edit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Dyode\Pricebeat\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Edit" name="dyode_pricebeat_form_edit"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="left">
        <block class="Dyode\Pricebeat\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Edit\Tabs" name="dyode_pricebeat_form_tabs">
            <block class="Dyode\Pricebeat\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Edit\Tab\Form" name="dyode_pricebeat_form_edit_tab_form"/>
            <action method="addTab">
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">form</argument>
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">dyode_pricebeat_form_edit_tab_form</argument>
            </action>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Dyode/Pricebeat/view/adminhtml/ui_component/dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_listing_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_listing_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">dyode_pricebeat_form_columns</item>
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
<dataSource name="dyode_pricebeat_form_listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">DyodePricebeatformGridDataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">dyode_pricebeat_form_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">form_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">form_id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
<container name="listing_top">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <bookmark name="bookmarks">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">dyode_pricebeat_form_listing</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </bookmark>
    <component name="columns_controls">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_columns</item>
                </item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </component>
    <exportButton name="export_button">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_columns.ids</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </exportButton>
    <filterSearch name="fulltext">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_listing_data_source</item>
                <item name="chipsProvider" xsi:type="string">dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.listing_top.listing_filters_chips</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.search</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </filterSearch>
    <filters name="listing_filters">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_columns</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                </item>
                <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                    <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </filters>
    <massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_columns.ids</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">form_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <action name="delete">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="dyode_pricebeat/form/massDelete"/>
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete Banners</item>
                        <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected Banners?</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
        <action name="edit">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Edit</item>
                    <item name="callback" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_columns_editor</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">editSelected</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
    </massaction>
    <paging name="listing_paging">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                </item>
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_columns.ids</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </paging>
</container>
<columns name="dyode_pricebeat_form_columns">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
            </item>
            <item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_columns.ids</item>
                <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">form_id</item>
                <item name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="dyode_pricebeat/form/inlineEdit"/>
                    <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_columns_editor</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <selectionsColumn name="ids">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">form_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </selectionsColumn>
    <column name="form_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="title">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="status">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="updated_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Modified</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Dyode\Pricebeat\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\formActions">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">form_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </actionsColumn>
</columns>
<container name="sticky">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/sticky/sticky</item>
            <item name="toolbarProvider" xsi:type="string">dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.listing_top</item>
            <item name="listingProvider" xsi:type="string">dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_listing.dyode_pricebeat_form_columns</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</container>
</listing>
```

**app/code/Dyode/Pricebeat/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/formActions.php**

```
<?php
namespace Dyode\Pricebeat\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

class formActions extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
 {
  /**
   * Url path  to edit
   *
   * @var string
  */
const URL_PATH_EDIT = 'dyode_pricebeat/form/edit';

/**
 * Url path  to delete
 *
 * @var string
 */
const URL_PATH_DELETE = 'dyode_pricebeat/form/delete';

/**
 * URL builder
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
 */
protected $urlBuilder;

/**
 * constructor
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
 * @param array $components
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
    array $components = [],
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
}


/**
 * Prepare Data Source
 *
 * @param array $dataSource
 * @return array
 */
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
            if (isset($item['form_id'])) {
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = [
                    'edit' => [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                            static::URL_PATH_EDIT,
                            [
                                'form_id' => $item['form_id']
                            ]
                        ),
                        'label' => __('Edit')
                    ],
                    'delete' => [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                            static::URL_PATH_DELETE,
                            [
                                'form_id' => $item['form_id']
                            ]
                        ),
                        'label' => __('Delete'),
                        'confirm' => [
                            'title' => __('Delete "${ $.$data.title }"'),
                            'message' => __('Are you sure you wan\'t to delete the Form "${ $.$data.title }" ?')
                        ]
                    ]
                ];
            }
        }
    }
    return $dataSource;
}
}
```

**app/code/Dyode/Pricebeat/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<virtualType name="DyodePricebeatGirdFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
            <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<virtualType name="DyodePricebeatformGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Dyode\Pricebeat\Model\ResourceModel\Video\Collection</argument>
        <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">DyodePricebeatGirdFilterPool</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<type name="Dyode\Pricebeat\Model\ResourceModel\Form\Grid\Collection">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">dyode_pricebeat_form</argument>
        <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">dyode_pricebeat_form_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">form_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Dyode\Pricebeat\Model\ResourceModel\Form</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dyode_pricebeat_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Dyode\Pricebeat\Model\ResourceModel\Form\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
 </config>
```

the adminside only show the title and button
[image]

Comment: You mean to say,  you want to display gird here like product gird ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Your handle name is different in the di.xml file hence the uicomponent didn't find a handle its throwing error.

  Your datasource name should be dyode_pricebeat_listing_data_source
  not dyode_pricebeat_form_listing_data_source

    https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224369/i-want-to-create-admin-grid-using-ui-component-if-you-have-any-article-or-blog/224381#224381
```